# Android Remove Gap in Settings menu item

Tags: android

How could I remove icons gap in float action menu. I want to have settings without icons.
See images:
[image]

Here menu code

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_delete"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Delete email"
    android:titleCondensed="Delete">
</item>

<item
android:id="@+id/menu_more"
android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_light"
android:title="Settings"
android:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/submenu_readAllJobs"
            android:title="@string/ReadAllJobsEmail"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/submenu_deleteAllJobs"
            android:title="@string/DeleteAllJobsEmail"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved problem by changing menu code to following:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_delete"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Delete email"
    android:titleCondensed="Delete">
</item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/submenu_readAllJobs"
    android:title="@string/ReadAllJobsEmail"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/submenu_deleteAllJobs"
    android:title="@string/DeleteAllJobsEmail"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    />
```

Result image:
[image]